# укажите мне на ошибку которую не замечаю цикл, while

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = "if you want to buy ticket, please enter how old are you: "
a += "Enter 'quit' when you are finished! "
while True:
    age = input(a)
    if a == 'quit':
        break
    elif age > 3:
        print('price for ticket is free!')
    elif 3 < age < 12:
        print('price for ticket is 15')
    elif age > 12:
        print('price for ticket is 20')
```

Я понимаю, что надо где то надо добавить `int()`, но не получается у меня! Благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С минимальными правками кода (в местах сравнения с числами "добавляем" `int()`):

```
a = "if you want to buy ticket, please enter how old are you: "
a += "Enter 'quit' when you are finished! "
while True:
    age = input(a)
    if a == 'quit':
        break
    elif int(age) > 3:
        print('price for ticket is free!')
    elif 3 < int(age) < 12:
        print('price for ticket is 15')
    elif int(age) > 12:
        print('price for ticket is 20')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поместить в переменную `age` не строку, а числовое значение, тогда вам будут доступны операции сравнения.

```
while True:
    input_string = input(a)

    if input_string == 'quit':
        break

    if not input_string.isnumeric():
        print('Age must be a number!')

    age = int(input_string)
    if age > 3:
        print('price for ticket is free!')
    elif 3 < age < 12:
        print('price for ticket is 15')
    elif age > 12:
        print('price for ticket is 20')
```

Comment: @Miron судя по тексту вопроса, автора знает про `int`

Comment: Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 0):

к вас неправильное условие `elif age > 3:`

```
while True:
    input_string = input("\nif you want to buy ticket, please enter how old are you ('quit' - Выход): ")

    if input_string == 'quit':
        break

    if not input_string.isnumeric():
        print('Age must be a number!')

    age = int(input_string)
    if age <= 3:                              # <----
        print('цена за билет бесплатно!!')
    elif 3 < age < 12:
        print('price for ticket is 15')
    elif age >= 12:
        print('price for ticket is 20')
```